# Scraping images from newspaper sites

Tags: r, image, url, rvest, scrape

Apologies for the remedial question (I'm an old professor and not terribly technological).

I'm using rvest to scrape images from newspaper sites using this code:

```
read_html(url) %>% html_nodes("img") %>% html_attr("src")
```

Some work well, but some do not.  I've had particular difficulty with:

https://www.argusleader.com/picture-gallery/news/2020/03/28/photos-coronavirus-impact-sioux-falls/2932927001/

The code returns:
character(0)

My best guess is that I am not properly identifying the node or attribute tags in the original html code.  I have tried numerous variations with little success.

Can someone provide guidance on common node or attributes that can be used to scrape images from sites such as these?

Thank you.

Comment: Please be sure all of your actions follow the terms of service: https://cm.argusleader.com/terms/.  For this page it is a matter of drilling down to the correct tag.  This should get you started: `page<-read_html(url);  
  page%>% html_nodes("media-gallery-vertical") %>% html_children()`

Comment: Have a look at https://selectorgadget.com/ to find the right selectors

Answer (score 1):

The website you gave uses JS to provide code dynamically. The solid way is to use RSelenium, but you can take a look at the page source first. In this situation, the website has the urls in `<slide>` tags and somehow converts them to `<img>` tags. This code will give you the result you probably desire:

```
library(rvest)
pg <- read_html("https://www.argusleader.com/picture-gallery/news/2020/03/28/photos-coronavirus-impact-sioux-falls/2932927001/")
imgs <- pg %>% html_nodes("slide") %>% html_attr("original")
```